# JWT tutorial needed

Tags: android, jwt

How to store the json web token of the login from my web api in my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I've already solved the problem. I've used Google Volley method to sent post and retrieve server response with the token. Below are the code sample where I've implemented the volley API.

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url_login,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"On Response "+response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    ValidateLogin(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
                    if (networkResponse != null && networkResponse.data != null) {
                        String jsonError = new String(networkResponse.data);
                        String message_response=null;
                        try {
                            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonError);
                            message_response= object.getString("error");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "On Error " + message_response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        showProgress(false);
                    }
                }
            })
```